# Protractor jasmine2-html-reporterHTML verify element was clicked

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jasmine2.0

My jasmine-spec-reporter verifies that an element was clicked I see the check marks in the console view however in my protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter shows that the spec was skipped when it was actually clicked. How can I correct this?

[image]

I Know this has something to do with an expect statement for example this visually shows passed expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://adp.com');

[image]

However I am stomped on how to write and expect statement to show an element was clicked so that the protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter shows passed. Any Help would be appreciated. this is my code below

```
 it('Load WFN home page - completed', function() {
        browser.get('https://wfn-iat.adp.com/public/index.htm');
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://wfn-iat.adp.com/public/index.htm');
    });

    it('click admin login - completed', function () {
        var adminlogin;
         adminlogin = ($('#adminLogin'));
        browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(adminlogin), 5000).then(function() {
        adminlogin.click();
          // browser.sleep(10000);
        });
```

Comment: it looks like I will have to go to the page after the click to verify that the link was actually click and verify and attribute on that page for the to get a pass for protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter. This actually worked this is some of the code i used.

expect(userid.getAttribute('class')).toEqual('forgotUID');

However if there is another way which out having to write some much code it would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `expect(EC.stalenessOf($('#adminLogin'),1000)).toBeTruthy()`, so you check, if the Button is no longer present in the DOM.

That way the test would fail on invalid credentials, because in those case you'd probably stay on the page and show some error.

Also using `.not` seems an option, so something like:  `expect($('#adminLogin')).not.toBePresent()`